# How to get rid of the red cross in the UI text in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button

i am making a boba fett game. I have made a scene where you can play the level again if you complete it. But I have a red cross in the UI text. Does anyone know how to get rid of them? And is that the reason why the 'play again' button doesnt work?

[image: Here is the text with the red cross]

Comment: This happens if your Rect has some **negative** size ... e.g. in a dynamic scaling rect if the offsets from the borders are bigger than the rect itself ... looks like you have some background images which invalid scales there since the text itself is rendered correctly

Answer (score 1):

in this picture seems your button is show back , when your button flip back , red line shown , and that's reason you can't click that . at first check buttons transform and change that

Answer (score 0):

To clarify you need to have width and height in the image transform rect as positive values, otherwise that red cross will be shown on the scene view:

[image]